# Azure Service Bus QueueClient Performance

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am having a hard time getting a good hit from Google on this.  I have a web application, that makes uses of the QueueClient to queue messages whenever users create records. What I want is a way to "fire and forget, but trust within reason".  That is to say:

- I want to be able to fire off a message to the bus and have it return immediately (so the user doesn't have to wait
- I want the message to be pooled locally (buffered? batched?) such that the system sends 1,5, 50 up at a time, within a given period of time.  So "send when the buffer is > 10 or 5 seconds has passed
- The buffer is paged to disk, such that if the system reboots or something, it will attempt to deliver again
- If all else fails, oh well.

I feel like I have read about buffering/batching in the QueueClient, but now I can't find anything about it.  Is it safe to re-use QueueClients across threads (requests) in a web application?

Does anyone have a suggested pattern or framework for achieving the above?

Currently, I am caching a shared QueueClient in a static variable (_client) - perhaps this is not correct.  Should I be caching and reusing the client or the factory?

```
private static QueueClient GetQueueClient()
    {
        if (_client == null || _client.IsClosed)
        {
            // Create management credentials
            TokenProvider credentials = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(
                Settings.ServiceBusIssuer, 
                Settings.ServiceBusIssuerKey);

            //create the client object for the queue
            MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.Create(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "Magic", string.Empty), credentials);

            string queueName = Crelate.Properties.Settings.Default.ServiceBusQueueName;
            QueueClient client = factory.CreateQueueClient(queueName);
            _client = client;

            return client;
        }

        return _client;
    }
```

I then do this, which definitely doesn't seem to be what I want:

```
QueueClient client = GetQueueClient();
BrokeredMessage msg = new BrokeredMessage(opInfo);
msg.MessageId = "SomeUsefulId";
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginSend, client.EndSend, msg, null);
```

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Of course, after writing all this, I found the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528527.aspx (Which mentions client-side batching and retry logic)

Comment: client side batching was indeed going to be my answer to this.  good catch

Comment: I still want a really reliable way to trust client side batching.  I want fire and forget ideally.